# Is it OK to do about 100 queries to Android SQLite database to save a data item?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I've been implementing SQLite data storage for my Android translator app.
The situation is: the app receives traslation as a JSON from server, parses it and builds an object tree (50 to 100 objects in average);
Now I need to save it into SQLite DB. I've asked my teacher, and he recommended not to save the whole JSON response but to make a more complex DB structure.
I've done so, but I'm concerned for those 50-100 DB queries, which are done (and, respectively, 50-100 rows created) to save just one dictionary article.

Now I'm wondering what is the best way to store complex object tree in DB or if it is OK to do up to 100 DB queries.

Maybe, nevertheless, the better way is to store the JSON response in DB? The only operation over the dictionary articles I need is to search them, no modification is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to have a proper database structure and normalised data. This will allow you to query your data more efficiently. Also, it will be much easier to understand for other people if they ever develop your code.

You should do all your updates in one transaction and you will be fine with saving 100 records in one go. You can use a structure similar to that one:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase(); // this returns a database
    db.beginTransaction();

    try {
        // all your updates
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
      db.endTransaction();
    }

    db.close();
```

Comment: well, but then I'll need to extract the object tree from DB, and, as I understand, there's no easy way to get it from tens of rows...

Comment: Why is there no easy way? Is your object so complex it will result in a lot of tables?

Comment: all the objects in my object trees are equal, so I decided to store them all in one table and connections between them in another one. I meant, when I will have extracted the connections for one object, I will need to do a query for each of the connections to extract the objects, which are connected to the current one, won't I?

Comment: As SQLite doesn't support common table expressions, you may cheat a bit and store the root of your tree for each record, get them all ine one go and restore the tree in the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use transactions properly, you'll be fine. Do all the writes within a single transaction and commit the transaction when complete.